# Need help to call my own api in api.ai

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es

I am trying to configre api.ai with my own restful API.
  Here i am getting issue when trying to get response from webhook.

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Actually i am not able to get any response from my restfull API which is deployed on wildfly. i added my api's url in fullfillment

Comment: You also need to check "Use webhook" in intents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small video I created for creating webhooks for API.AI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cD9vU7Ubyg&t=31s

Please comment if you still face any issue.